# list sorting returning unexpected output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input

```
4
2 4 5 9
4
2 4 11 12
```

Output

```
11 
12 
5 
9
```

Expected output

```
5
9
11
12
```

I was expecting the list to be sorted but it is getting sorted according to the sets , even after it was converted from the set to a list.

Code

```
m = int(input())
minp=input().split()
n = int(input())
ninp=input().split()
a,b=set(minp),set(ninp)
set3=list(b.difference(a).union(a.difference(b)))
set3.sort()
for i in set3:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set3` contains strings, so `sort` is sorting the strings lexicographically.

Convert the Strings to numbers first before sorting:

```
set3 = [int(n) for n in set3]
set3.sort()
```